# How to get data from multiple elements

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

i have next ViewModel:

```
public class ChatCreationViewModel
    {
        public string ChatName { get; set; }
        public List<User> Friends { get; set; }
        public List<(string, bool)> Partcipants { get; set; }
    }
```

and next view:

```
@model GalkaNet.ViewModels.ChatCreationViewModel

    <form method="post" asp-action="NewChat" asp-controller="Chat" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2>Создание беседы</h2>
        <label>Chat name: </label> <input type="text" name="ChatName" placeholder="Name" value=""></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
        @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Friends.Count; i++)
        {
    <div>
        <label>@Model.Friends[i].NickName</label>
        <p> @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Partcipants[i].Item2)</p>
    </div>
        }
    </form>
</div>
```

The thing is: i want to create a list of elements with user names and checkboxes. Once the form is submitted i want to place values from each checkbox combined with id of user (in front of whose name this checbox was) into Partcipants list of my view model that is going to server. How should i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Model Like this

```
public string ChatName { get; set; }
public List<UserModel > Friends { get; set; }
```

Your User Model Properties(ID,UserName,isSelected)
Fill these properties from your db

```
Id = friend.Id;
UserName = friend.Name,
isSelected = false
```

Your View

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Friends.Count; i++)
  {
   <div class="form-check m-1">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Friend[i].Id " />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Friend[i].Username" />
        <input asp-for="@Model.Friend[i].isSelected" class="form-check- 
       input" />
        <label class="form-check-label" asp- 
        for="@Model.Friend[i].isSelected">
        @Model.Friend[i].Username </label>
  </div>
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.